# Errors Mpgraph in ConTeXt

Tags: context, metapost

I need to put some bar charts in a ConTeXt document. I'm using mkiv from TeX Live 2011, under Gentoo GNU/Linux. I tried using Gnuplot but I found `mpgraph` suits better my needs.

I'm using this TeX file

```
\usemodule[graph]
\usemodule[sarith]

\enableregime[utf-8]
\starttext

\startMPcode
beginfig(1)
  draw begingraph(12cm,6cm);
    glabel.lft(btex Eje Y etex, OUT);
    glabel.bot(btex Eje X etex, OUT);
    gdata("data.d",
        $,
        path p;
        augment.p (0,$1);
        augment.p ($2,$1);
        augment p ($2,$1 Sadd "1");
        augment p (0,$1 Sadd "1");
        gdraw p withpen pencircle scaled 2bp withcolor red;
    );
  autogrid(grid.bot,grid.lft) withcolor .85white;
  endgraph;
endfig;
\stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

and this data file

```
1 4
2 2
3 1
4 2
5 4
```

as a minimal 'working' example.

However, some strange is happening: I can't use any operator from `sarith` module (used in `mpgraph` module for drawing boxes). I got [this output](http://pastebin.com/7J4gh2KU) with ConTeXt. I tried compiling with Metapost, although I got no errors or warnings the output .dvi is corrupted.

I've tried also with TeX Live 2012 under Windows 7. I can't compile there because of the `sarith` thing, but when I comment that lines it works. But doing the same thing in my Gentoo box works, excepting that text for labels or axis doesn't appear, just a very little square. I don't understand what is happening, even the example from the ConTeXt wiki doesn't work. Clues? Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Try to take off `beginfig(1)`/`endfig` when you run with `context`,

Comment: BTW, you should also check the `pgfplots` package (which is supposed to work with ConTeXt as well). Metapost provides only a limited plotting capabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to replace `\usepackage[sarith]` with

```
\startMPinitializations
input sarith;
\stopMPinitializations
```

`sarith` is not a ConTeXt module, rather it is a metapost package, so needs to be included at the metapost end.

Moreover, as morbusg pointed out, there is no need to add `beginfig(1)...endfig` in a `MPcode` environment. With these two changes, the following works:

```
\usemodule[graph]
\startMPinitializations
input sarith;
\stopMPinitializations

\starttext

\startMPcode
  draw begingraph(12cm,6cm);
    glabel.lft(btex Eje Y etex, OUT);
    glabel.bot(btex Eje X etex, OUT);
    gdata("data.d",
        $,
        path p;
        augment.p (0,$1);
        augment.p ($2,$1);
        augment p ($2,$1 Sadd "1");
        augment p (0,$1 Sadd "1");
        gdraw p withpen pencircle scaled 2bp withcolor red;
    );
  autogrid(grid.bot,grid.lft) withcolor .85white;
  endgraph;
\stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

Comment: You're a genius, you saved my life again! Thank you so much! In fact, fonts showed up! Now I will look up for how change them in Metapost. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using MkIV, just change the main doucment font and the change will be reflected in metapost as well.

Comment: Nope, it only changes the font for `glabel`. Numbers on grids are plotted in cmr and labels with the default LaTeX fixed font.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example? If I add `\setupbodyfont[times]` in the above example, only TeXGyre Theremes is used.

Comment: [Here's the example](http://pastebin.com/RtapvtkN), [here's the typescript I'm using](http://pastebin.com/2PemxuPE) (can't share the font due to its license) and [the data file](http://pastebin.com/nKmpkbET). I added a third column values 'cause I need to plot text labels on the axis, but I don't know how to workaround with the spaces on labels. I found out that `mpgraph` is rendering text with math font, that's because the typescript fails. Just changed `\setupbodyfont[times]` to `\setupbodyfont[droid]`, it didn't work either. I looked for type-win.mkiv but don't know how it does the trick.

Comment: `mpgraph` uses a math font because the labels can have things like `3 \times 10^6`. You have two options, either add a matching math font to your typescript, or change the `metapost.format_n` function from `m-graph.mkiv`.

Comment: BTW, ConTeXt does not come with a typescript for droid font. `type-win` is for MkII typescripts. MkIV typescripts are in `type-otf.mkiv`. You can also use simplefont module for setting fonts.

Comment: Edited `m-graph.mkiv`. Still looking for changing the mono font, but the rest worked! Thank you so much for all your patiente and explanations!

Answer (score 1):

To change the font for the numbers on the grids I discovered that if I manually set the grid values, instead of using the automatic set, the font is converted to the document format. Here is an example from John Handy's MPGraph documentation with my revision:

Original

```
draw begingraph(6.5cm,4.5cm);
    setrange(80,0, 90,whatever);
        glabel.bot(btex Year etex, OUT);
        glabel.lft(btex \vbox{\hbox{Emissions in} \hbox{thousands of}
            \hbox{metric tons} \hbox{(heavy line)}}etex, OUT);
        gdraw "lead.d" withpen pencircle scaled 1.5pt;
        autogrid(,otick.lft);
        setcoords(linear,linear);
    setrange(80,0, 90,whatever);
        glabel.rt(btex \vbox{\hbox{Micrograms} \hbox{per cubic}
            \hbox{meter of air} \hbox{(thin line)}}etex, OUT);
    gdraw "lead.d";
        autogrid(otick.bot,otick.rt);
endgraph;
```

with

```
draw begingraph(6.5cm,4.5cm);
    setrange(79.5,0, 90.5,80) ;
    glabel.bot(btex Year etex, OUT) shifted(-8pt,-2pt);
    glabel.lft(btex \vbox{% -- \hss fills space horizontally; \strut fixes line space
        \hbox to 5cm {\hss \strut Emissions in thousands of \hss}
        \hbox to 5cm {\hss \strut metric tons (solid line) \hss}
    }
    etex, OUT) shifted(83pt,17pt) rotated 90;
    gdraw "lead.d" withpen pencircle scaled 1pt;
    itick.lft(format("\%2",0),0) withcolor white;
    itick.lft(format("\%2",20),20) withcolor white;
    itick.lft(format("\%2",40),40) withcolor white;
    itick.lft(format("\%2",60),60) withcolor white;
    itick.lft(format("\%2",80),80) withcolor white;
    frame.lft withcolor white ;

    otick.bot(format("\%2",80),80) withcolor white;
    otick.bot(format("\%2",82),82) withcolor white;
    otick.bot(format("\%2",84),84) withcolor white;
    otick.bot(format("\%2",86),86) withcolor white;
    otick.bot(format("\%2",88),88) withcolor white;
    otick.bot(format("\%2",90),90) withcolor white;
endgraph;
```

Try this out.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this today. It worked well! Thanks